# Composition of mapping? | Converting (roman) Velthuis encoding to IAST transliteration

Tags: xetex, mapping, transliteration, devanagari

My question is a follow-up of this question asked a decade ago: [Transliteration in Devanagari](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40879/transliteration-in-devanagari).

I want to convert roman text (in Velthuis encoding) into both

1. sanskrit text (in devanagari script), and
2. IAST transliteration.

I achieve the roman to devanagari conversion using `veltuis-sanskrit` mapping provided by `devanagari` package.

Regarding the second part (roman to IAST transliteration), there has been an attempt to obtain IAST transliteration from devanagari text here: [Reversing Text Mapping (Devanagari to IAST Transliteration)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502515/reversing-text-mapping-devanagari-to-iast-transliteration?noredirect=1&lq=1). How to achieve this conversion from roman text?

Essentially I want to achieve a compounding of the two maps

1. `velthuis-sanskrit` (roman to devanagari)
2. `deva-to-iast` provided [here](https://gist.github.com/hrishikeshrt/c35e1a5332a4fbcdcdf7102446d2e796) (devanagari to IAST)

Is there a way to achieve this simply by doing a composition of the two maps (say using `teckit`) and produce a new map?

**MWE**

What I want to achieve is captivated in the fourth line marked with exclamations.

I want to define `\romiastfont` such that the last two lines give the same output.

**Is it possible to define a new map as the composition of these two maps (`velthuis-sanskrit` and `deva-to-iast`) and then define `\romiastfont` based on the new mapping? Can this be done using `teckit`?**

```tex
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Gargi}[
    Script=Devanagari,
    Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gargi/,
    UprightFont=Gargi,
    Extension=.ttf,
    %Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit
]
\newfontfamily{\romdevfont}{Gargi}[
    Script=Devanagari,
    Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Gargi/,
    UprightFont=Gargi,
    Extension=.ttf,
    Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit
]
\newfontfamily{\iastfont}{times}[
    Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/,
    UprightFont=times,
    BoldFont=timesbd,
    Extension=.ttf,
    Mapping=deva-to-iast % deva-to-iast.tec obtained from here (and compiled): https://gist.github.com/hrishikeshrt/c35e1a5332a4fbcdcdf7102446d2e796
]

\catcode`\~=12

\begin{document}
    \noindent\textsanskrit{रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे}\\ % direct sanskrit
    \romdevfont{raamo raajama.ni sadaa vijayate raama.m rame"sa.m bhaje}\\ % roman to sanskrit
    \iastfont{रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे}\\ % sanskrit to IAST
    \newcommand{\romiastfont}[1]{\iastfont{\romdevfont{#1}}} % <-- !!! roman to IAST; doesn't work; what should this be?
    \romiastfont{raamo raajama.ni sadaa vijayate raama.m rame"sa.m bhaje} % expect this to be same as previous line
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have used different texts, what is the expected IAST?

Comment: You don't seem to be aware that `\iastfont` is a declaration, not a command with argument. Anyway, I don't think this is possible: when you do `\textsanskrit{<text>}` the text is typeset in the chosen Devanagari font (with the stated mapping applied). Stating `\iastfont` around it does nothing at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @egreg, I have edited my question. Hope it is more clear now. I essentially want that magic definition of `\romiastfont` :)

Comment: The font can be any suitable typeface. The transliteration scheme (e.g., typing `k` to print a `क`) is separate from the font.

Comment: @Cicada, I couldn't understand you completely (I am just a beginner in this). But my main question was whether it is possible to do a composition of two mappings (roman to devanagari and devanagari to IAST) to achieve the desired (roman to IAST)? And then the command `\romiastfont` can be defined based on this new mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fairly easily write a map file I think, this is enough to do the example given (I had to change the fonts) Note the declared font commands in your question do not take an argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[
    Script=Devanagari,
    %Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit
]
\newfontfamily{\romdevfont}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[
    Script=Devanagari,
    Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit
]
\newfontfamily{\iastfont}{Times New Roman}[
    Mapping=deva-to-iast % deva-to-iast.tec obtained from here (and compiled): https://gist.github.com/hrishikeshrt/c35e1a5332a4fbcdcdf7102446d2e796
]

\newfontfamily{\romiastfont}{Times New Roman}[
    Mapping=deva2 % 
]

\catcode`\~=12

\begin{document}
    \textsanskrit{रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे}% direct sanskrit

    {\romdevfont raamo raajama.ni sadaa vijayate raama.m rame"sa.m bhaje}% \romdevfont does not have {} % roman to sanskrit

    {\iastfont रामो राजमणि सदा विजयते रामं रमेशं भजे} % sanskrit to IAST \iast font does not have {}

    {\romiastfont raamo raajama.ni sadaa vijayate raama.m rame"sa.m bhaje} % expect this to be same as previous line
\end{document}
```

Using a compiled `deva2.map` file

```
LHSName "deva2"
pass(Unicode)
U+0061 U+0061 <>U+0101; aa
U+002E U+006E <>U+1E47; .n
U+002E U+006D <>U+1E43; .m
U+0022 U+0073 <>U+015B;  "s
```

Comment: Thank you! By any chance, is there a way to generate the complete mapping automatically?

Comment: @Zxcvasdf not as far as I know but I am not an expert (I can not read Devanagari)  but the mapping is simpler than either of the mappings you suggested composing as you only need cases where they are different, so places where the columns here show different entries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velthuis#Transliteration_scheme

Answer (score 1):

Following @David Carlisle's suggestion, I have tried to create a map that converts Velthuis encoding to IAST transliteration.

https://gist.github.com/vachan-potluri/6c26a7963bf8323b8709f2d3136ef8ec

```
; Velthuis encoding to IAST transliteration
; motivated by velthuis-sanskrit.map from xetex-devanagari and deva-to-iast.map from
; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502515/reversing-text-mapping-devanagari-to-iast-transliteration?noredirect=1&lq=1
; Also see
; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velthuis#Transliteration_scheme, and
; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration#Transliteration_comparison
LHSName  "Velthuis-Sanskrit-IAST"
RHSName  "UNICODE"
LHSDescription "Velthuis Devanagari for IAST Sanskrit transliteration"
Version  "1"

Define a U+0061  ;a
Define d U+0064  ;d
Define h U+0068  ;h
Define i U+0069  ;i
Define l U+006C  ;l
Define m U+006D  ;m
Define n U+006E  ;n
Define r U+0072  ;r
Define o U+006F  ;o
Define s U+0073  ;s
Define t U+0074  ;t
Define u U+0075  ;u

Define quot U+0022
Define dot  U+002E
Define tlde U+007E

Define Asvara U+0101
Define Isvara U+012B
Define Usvara U+016B
Define rvoc U+1E5B
Define Rvoc U+1E5D
Define lvoc U+1E37
Define Lvoc U+1E39
Define bindu U+1E43
Define visarga U+1E25
Define avagraha U+0027

pass(Unicode)
a a <> Asvara
i i <> Isvara
u u <> Usvara
dot r <> rvoc
dot r r <> Rvoc
dot l <> lvoc
dot l l <> Lvoc
dot m <> bindu
dot h <> visarga
dot a <> avagraha
quot n <> U+1E45; ṅ
tlde n <> U+00F1; ñ
dot t <> U+1E6D; ṭ
dot d <> U+1E0D; ḍ
dot n <> U+1E47; ṇ
quot s <> U+015B; ś
dot s <> U+1E63; ṣ
dot o <> o U+1E43; oṃ
```

I have not yet tested it thoroughly. It would be great if anyone would test and provide comments/improvements for this. It currently works for the MWE posted in the question.

Comment: +1 looks  bit more complete than my version:-)

Answer (score 0):

Mapping using expl3, and compiling with lualatex.

[image: mapped]

Compiling a `.map` file with TECkit is not required with this method.

Using expl3 to bring the regex into LaTeX that implements the mapping allows the use of a reference lookup table (stored as an expl3 sequence (=set)) as a mapping repository, in turn allowing many-to-many joins between an open-ended set of mapping schemes, all under user control.

Record example

[image: record]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontscript{Devanagari}{dev2,deva}
\newfontfamily\fdevb[Script=Devanagari,Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Shobhika}
\newfontfamily\fipa{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\ExplSyntaxOn
        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { cno }
        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
                    \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                { cnx }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_count_tokens:n 
            { V }
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_replace_all:Nnn
            { Nxx }


\tl_new:N \g_fctr_ns_tl % 
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_ic_mfsq_seq
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_ic_mfsqz_seq
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_ic_mfsqy_seq
    \tl_new:N 
            \l_ic_mfsqz_tl
    \seq_new:N 
            \l_ic_mfsqyy_seq
    \int_new:N 
            \l_ic_mfsqz_int
    \int_new:N 
            \l_ic_mfsqy_int
\seq_new:N \l_trtmpa_seq
\tl_new:N \l_mytr_tl
%---12
    \cs_set:Nn \ic_vowelsxasciidevapost: {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { a }
                {  }
                \l_mytr_tl
}


%---21
    \cs_set:Nn \ic_vowelsdevaxasciipre: {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { ([क-ह]) }
                { 
                    \1
                    X
                 }
                \l_mytr_tl
}

%---21
    \cs_set:Nn \ic_vowelsdevaxasciipost: {
    % no end vowel
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (X)(\s) }
                { 
                    \2
                 }
                \l_mytr_tl
  % halant
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (X\c{&}) }
                { 
                    
                 }
                \l_mytr_tl
  % before non-inherent vowel
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (X)([aeiou\,\|]) }
                { 
                    \2
                 }
                \l_mytr_tl
  % is inherent vowel
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (X) }
                { 
                    a
                 }
                \l_mytr_tl
}




%---72
    \cs_set:Nn \ic_vowelsveltdevapre: {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\S)(aa) }
                { \1 a \c{Uchar} 2366 \c{tex_relax:D} }
                \l_mytr_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\S)(e) }
                { \1 a \c{Uchar} 2375 \c{tex_relax:D} }
                \l_mytr_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\S)(i) }
                { \1 a \c{Uchar} 2367 \c{tex_relax:D} }
                \l_mytr_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\S)(o) }
                { \1 a \c{Uchar} 2379 \c{tex_relax:D} }
                \l_mytr_tl

}


%---78
    \cs_set:Nn \ic_vowelsveltiastmid: {

    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { ([蝟-螃])([^蝐-蝞螈-螫]) }
                { \1 a }
                \l_mytranslitph_tl
}
%---78im
    \cs_set:Nn \ic_vowelsveltiastmidim: {
% no mid-processing required for 78im fibre
}



%---28
    \cs_set:Nn \ic_vowelsdevaiastpost: {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { ([hlmnrtv]{1})(/) }
                { \1 x\2 }
                \l_mytr_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { ([hlmnrtv]{1})([^(ā|i|/{3})]{1}) }
                { \1 a }
                \l_mytr_tl
%               ([^t]+|(t([^e]|$)|te([^s]|$)|tes([^t]|$)))+
%^((?!hede).)*$
}



%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_listseq:n #1 { % 1=pair (in record)
    
                        %----- store the record
                    \seq_set_split:cnx
                             { l_trtmpa_seq }
                            {; } % separator
                            { #1 }
                            
                    \noindent       
                    \group_begin:
                        \l_trns_formata_tl
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fielda_tl }
                    \group_end:     
                    
                    
                    \group_begin:
                    \tl_use:c { l_trns_formatmap_tl }
                    \group_end:     

                    \group_begin:
                        \l_trns_formatb_tl
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fieldb_tl }
                    \group_end:     
                    
                    \group_begin:
                    % postnote
                    \tl_if_empty:cF
                       { l_trns_fieldc_tl }
                       {
                      \tex_space:D
                      (
                        \l_trns_formatc_tl
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fieldc_tl }
                            )
                       
                       }
                    \group_end:     
                    \tex_par:D
    }

\tl_new:N \l_mytranslookup_tl
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_ttseq:n #1 { % 1=pair 
                        %----- store the record
                    \seq_set_split:cnx
                             { l_trtmpa_seq }
                            {; } % separator
                            { #1 }
        \tl_set:Nx                          
                \l_mytranslookup_tl
                  {
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fielda_tl } % field number in record (first of pair)
                                }               
                
        \tl_if_empty:NF
            \l_mytranslookup_tl
            { 
                        % if there is somthing to look up:  
                    \tl_replace_all:Nxx  
                            \l_mytr_tl 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fielda_tl } % field number in record (first of pair)
                             } 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fieldb_tl }% field number in record (second of pair)
                             } 
                    
                } % end lookup
    }

\tl_new:N \l_mytranslitph_tl

%Two-step: all-from to unique
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_ttseqa:n #1 { % 1=pair 
                        %----- store the record
                    \seq_set_split:cnx
                             { l_trtmpa_seq }
                            {; } % separator
                            { #1 }
        \tl_set:Nx                          
                \l_mytranslookup_tl
                  {
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fielda_tl } % field number in record (first of pair)
                                }               
        \tl_if_empty:NF
            \l_mytranslookup_tl
            { 
                        % if there is somthing to look up:  
                    \int_set:Nn 
                            \l_tmpa_int 
                            { 
                            34633 + 
                            \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                           { \l_trns_placeholder_tl }
                            }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nxx  
                            \l_mytr_tl 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fielda_tl } % field number in record (first of pair)
                             } 
                            { 
                            \Uchar \l_tmpa_int
                             } 
        } % end lookup
    }

%Two-step: unique to all-to
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_ttseqb:n #1 { % 1=pair 
                %----- store the record
                    \seq_set_split:cnx
                             { l_trtmpa_seq }
                            {; } % separator
                            { #1 }
                    \int_set:Nn 
                            \l_tmpa_int 
                            { 
                            34633 + 
                            \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                           { \l_trns_placeholder_tl }
                            }       
                            
                    \tl_replace_all:Nxx  
                            \l_mytranslitph_tl 
                            { 
                            \Uchar \l_tmpa_int
                             } 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fieldb_tl }% field number in record (second of pair)
                             } 
    }

%intermediate
\tl_new:N \l_mytranslitim_tl
%Two-step: all-from to im
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_ttseqima:n #1 { % 1=pair 
                %----- store the record
                    \seq_set_split:cnx
                             { l_trtmpa_seq }
                            {; } % separator
                            { #1 }
        \tl_set:Nx                          
                \l_mytranslookup_tl
                  {
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fielda_tl } % field number in record (first of pair)
                                }               
        \tl_if_empty:NF
            \l_mytranslookup_tl
            { 
                        % if there is somthing to look up:  
                    \tl_replace_all:Nxx  
                            \l_mytr_tl 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fielda_tl } % field number in record (first of pair)
                             } 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                           { \l_trns_intermediate_tl }
                             } 
        } % end lookup
    }

%Two-step: im to all-to

%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_ttseqimb:n #1 { % 1=pair 
                    %----- store the record
                    \seq_set_split:cnx
                             { l_trtmpa_seq }
                            {; } % separator
                            { #1 }
                    \tl_replace_all:Nxx  
                            \l_mytranslitim_tl 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                           { \l_trns_intermediate_tl }
                             } 
                            { 
                        \seq_item:Nn
                           \l_trtmpa_seq 
                                { \l_trns_fieldb_tl }% field number in record (second of pair)
                             } 
    }
%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_sortseq:cnn #1#2#3 { 
    % 1=seq, 
    % 2=order (<:descending, >:ascending) 
    % 3=sort field
    
    \seq_sort:cn  { #1 } %\l_ic_mfsq_seq 
        {
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_seq 
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_seq 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_seq 
                    {; } 
                    { ##1 }
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_seq 
                    {; } 
                    { ##2 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_ic_mfsqz_seq 
                                { #3 } % sort field
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_ic_mfsqy_seq 
                                { #3 } % sort field 
                    }

            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                                \l_ic_mfsqz_tl 
                    }
            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                        \l_ic_mfsqy_tl 
                    }
            \int_compare:nNnTF 
                    { \l_ic_mfsqz_int } { #2 } { \l_ic_mfsqy_int }
                    { \sort_return_swapped: }
                    { \sort_return_same: }
        }
}


%---
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_sortseqnum:cnn #1#2#3 { 
    % 1=seq, 
    % 2=order (<:descending, >:ascending) 
    % 3=sort field
    
    \seq_sort:cn  { #1 } %\l_ic_mfsq_seq 
        {
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_seq 
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_seq 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_seq 
                    {; } 
                    { ##1 }
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_seq 
                    {; } 
                    { ##2 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_ic_mfsqz_seq 
                                { #3 } % sort field
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_ic_mfsqy_seq 
                                { #3 } % sort field 
                    }

            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqz_int 
                    { 
%                       \tl_count_tokens:V 
                                \l_ic_mfsqz_tl 
                    }
            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_ic_mfsqy_int 
                    { 
%                       \tl_count_tokens:V 
                        \l_ic_mfsqy_tl 
                    }
            \int_compare:nNnTF 
                    { \l_ic_mfsqz_int } { #2 } { \l_ic_mfsqy_int }
                    { \sort_return_swapped: }
                    { \sort_return_same: }
        }
}

%-----
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfstrloadaseq } { o m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=data
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fctr_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fctr_ns_tl { #1 } }
    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
            }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
            { , } 
            { #3 }
}
%-----
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfssortaseq } { o m m m } { 
%1=namespace
%2=seqname, 
%3=><, asc/desc
%4=sort field
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fctr_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fctr_ns_tl { #1 } }
            \ic_sortseq:cnn 
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    { #3 } %desc/asc
                    { #4 } %sort field
}
%-----
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfssortaseqnum } { o m m m } { 
%1=namespace
%2=seqname, 
%3=><, asc/desc
%4=sort field
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fctr_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fctr_ns_tl { #1 } }
            \ic_sortseqnum:cnn 
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    { #3 } %desc/asc
                    { #4 } %sort field
}
%---
\keys_define:nn { trnsllist }
{
fielda .tl_set:c = { l_trns_fielda_tl },
fielda .initial:n = { 1 },
fielda .default:n = { 1 },
fieldb .tl_set:c = { l_trns_fieldb_tl },
fieldb .initial:n = { 2 },
fieldb .default:n = { 2 },
formata .tl_set:c = { l_trns_formata_tl },
formata .initial:n = { },
formata .default:n = { },
formatb .tl_set:c = { l_trns_formatb_tl },
formatb .initial:n = { },
formatb .default:n = { },
formatmap .tl_set:c = { l_trns_formatmap_tl },
formatmap .initial:n = { \tex_space:D $\mapsto$ \tex_space:D },
formatmap .default:n = {    \tex_space:D $\mapsto$ \tex_space:D },
placeholder .tl_set:c = { l_trns_placeholder_tl },
placeholder .initial:n = { },
placeholder .default:n = { },
fieldc .tl_set:c = { l_trns_fieldc_tl },
fieldc .initial:n = { },
fieldc .default:n = { },
formatc .tl_set:c = { l_trns_formatc_tl },
formatc .initial:n = { },
formatc .default:n = { },
showoriginal .bool_set:c = { l_trns_showoriginal_bool },
showoriginal .initial:n = {false},
showoriginal .default:n = {false},
intermediate .tl_set:c = { l_trns_intermediate_tl }, %bridge B: A>B>C
intermediate .initial:n = { },
intermediate .default:n = { },
}
%-----
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfslistaseq } { o m O{} } { 
%1=namespace
%2=seqname 
%3=keys
      \IfNoValueF{#3}
    {
        \keys_set:nn { trnsllist } { #3 } 
        }
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fctr_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fctr_ns_tl { #1 } }
        \seq_map_function:cN
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \ic_listseq:n 
}
\tl_new:N \l_mytranslitorig_tl
\regex_const:Nn \c_consonantaa_regex { ([rm]{1})(aa) }
\tl_new:N \l_trns_fieldxascii_tl
\tl_new:N \l_trns_fielddeva_tl
\tl_new:N \l_trns_fieldvelt_tl
\tl_new:N \l_trns_fieldiast_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_trns_fieldxascii_tl {1}
\tl_set:Nn \l_trns_fielddeva_tl {2}
\tl_set:Nn \l_trns_fieldvelt_tl {7}
\tl_set:Nn \l_trns_fieldiast_tl {8}
%-----
\NewDocumentCommand { \translitx } { o m O{} +m } { 
%1=namespace
%2=seqname 
%3=keys
%4=data
        \tl_set:Nx \l_mytr_tl { #4 }
      \IfNoValueF{#3}
    {
        \keys_set:nn { trnsllist } { #3 } 
        }
        \bool_if:NT
                \l_trns_showoriginal_bool  %  key
                {
                  \tl_set_eq:NN
                            \l_mytranslitorig_tl
                            \l_mytr_tl
                }
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fctr_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fctr_ns_tl { #1 } }
% pre-process vowels
%\ic_vowels2:
\tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fielda_tl
{
%  % 2 ---
    \l_trns_fielddeva_tl { 
                    \tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fieldb_tl
                    {
                            \l_trns_fieldxascii_tl { \ic_vowelsdevaxasciipre: }
                        } 
       }
  % 7 ---
    \l_trns_fieldvelt_tl { 
                    \tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fieldb_tl
                    {
                            \l_trns_fielddeva_tl { \ic_vowelsveltdevapre: }
                        } 
       }
} 
% -----
        \tl_if_empty:cTF
            { l_trns_placeholder_tl } % 34633
            {
                    \tl_if_empty:cTF
                        { l_trns_intermediate_tl }
                        {%not intermediate
                                %normal translit (A>B)
                                \seq_map_function:cN
                                            { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                                            \ic_ttseq:n 
                        }
                        {%intermediate
                                %A>im
                                \seq_map_function:cN
                                            { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                                            \ic_ttseqima:n 

                    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mytranslitim_tl \l_mytr_tl              
%---                                            
                    
% mid-process vowels (im)
\tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fielda_tl
{
  % 7 ---
    \l_trns_fieldvelt_tl { 
                    \tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fieldb_tl
                    {
                            \l_trns_fieldiast_tl { \ic_vowelsveltiastmidim: }
                        } 
       }
} 

%---                                            
                                %im>B
                                \seq_map_function:cN
                                            { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                                            \ic_ttseqimb:n 
                    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mytr_tl \l_mytranslitim_tl              
                        }                   
            }
            {
                %A>unique:
        \seq_map_function:cN
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \ic_ttseqa:n 
                    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mytranslitph_tl \l_mytr_tl              
% mid-process vowels
\tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fielda_tl
{
  % 7 ---
    \l_trns_fieldvelt_tl { 
                    \tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fieldb_tl
                    {
                            \l_trns_fieldiast_tl { \ic_vowelsveltiastmid: }
                        } 
       }
} 
                %unique>B:
        \seq_map_function:cN
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \ic_ttseqb:n 
                    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mytr_tl \l_mytranslitph_tl              
            }
        \bool_if:NT
                \l_trns_showoriginal_bool
                {
                        \group_begin:
                \l_trns_formata_tl
                  \tl_use:N
                            \l_mytranslitorig_tl
                    \group_end:     
                    {\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{it}\tex_space:D (original)}
                    \tex_par:D
                }
% post-process vowels
\tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fielda_tl
{
  % 1 --
  \l_trns_fieldxascii_tl { 
                    \tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fieldb_tl
                    {
                            \l_trns_fielddeva_tl { \ic_vowelsxasciidevapost: }
                        } 
       }
  
  % 2 ---
    \l_trns_fielddeva_tl { 
                    \tl_case:Nn   \l_trns_fieldb_tl
                    {
                            \l_trns_fieldxascii_tl { \ic_vowelsdevaxasciipost: }
                            \l_trns_fieldiast_tl { \ic_vowelsdevaiastpost: }
                        } 
       }

}
        {
          \group_begin:
                    \l_trns_formatb_tl
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytr_tl
                \group_end:
        }
}
%-----
\NewDocumentCommand { \translit } { o m O{} +m } { 
%1=namespace
%2=seqname 
%3=keys
%4=data

        \tl_set:Nx \l_mytr_tl { #4 }


 
      \IfNoValueF{#3}
    {
        \keys_set:nn { trnsllist } { #3 } 
        }
        \bool_if:NT
                \l_trns_showoriginal_bool  %  key
                {
                  \tl_set_eq:NN
                            \l_mytranslitorig_tl
                            \l_mytr_tl
                }
                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fctr_ns_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fctr_ns_tl { #1 } }
% -----
        \tl_if_empty:cTF
            { l_trns_placeholder_tl } % 34633
            {
        \seq_map_function:cN
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \ic_ttseq:n 
            }
            {
                %A:
        \seq_map_function:cN
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \ic_ttseqa:n 
                    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mytranslitph_tl \l_mytr_tl              
                %B:
        \seq_map_function:cN
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fctr_ns_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \ic_ttseqb:n 
                    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_mytr_tl \l_mytranslitph_tl              
            }
        \bool_if:NT
                \l_trns_showoriginal_bool
                {
                        \group_begin:
                \l_trns_formata_tl
                  \tl_use:N
                            \l_mytranslitorig_tl
                    \group_end:     
                    {\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{it}\tex_space:D (original)}
                    \tex_par:D
                }

        {
          \group_begin:
                    \l_trns_formatb_tl
                    \tl_use:N \l_mytr_tl
                \group_end:
        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\campersand{\&}
\begin{document}
%===
%1 = xascii
%2 = devanagari
%3 = Unicode name
%4 = record number
%5 = Unicode codepoint
%6 = placeholder (tempvar for 3-way)
%7 = Velthuis
%8 = IAST

\catcode `\~=12


\mfstrloadaseq[x]{devatranslit}{%
//;ऀ;U+0900 ऀ DEVANAGARI SIGN INVERTED CANDRABINDU;1;2304;x0001;;
,/;ँ;U+0901 ँ DEVANAGARI SIGN CANDRABINDU;2;2305;x0002;;˜ 
,.m;ं;U+0902 ं DEVANAGARI SIGN ANUSVARA;3;2306;x0003;.m;ṃ 
,.h;ः;U+0903 ः DEVANAGARI SIGN VISARGA;4;2307;x0004;.h;ḥ 
,a=;ऄ;U+0904 ऄ DEVANAGARI LETTER SHORT A;5;2308;x0005;;
,a-;अ;U+0905 अ DEVANAGARI LETTER A;6;2309;x0006;a;a 
,aa-;आ;U+0906 आ DEVANAGARI LETTER AA;7;2310;x0007;aa;ā 
,i-;इ;U+0907 इ DEVANAGARI LETTER I;8;2311;x0008;i;i 
,ii-;ई;U+0908 ई DEVANAGARI LETTER II;9;2312;x0009;ii;ī 
,u-;उ;U+0909 उ DEVANAGARI LETTER U;10;2313;x0010;u;u 
,uu-;ऊ;U+090A ऊ DEVANAGARI LETTER UU;11;2314;x0011;uu;ū 
,.r-;ऋ;U+090B ऋ DEVANAGARI LETTER VOCALIC R;12;2315;x0012;.r;ṛ 
,.l-;ऌ;U+090C ऌ DEVANAGARI LETTER VOCALIC L;13;2316;x0013;.l;ḷ 
,~e;ऍ;U+090D ऍ DEVANAGARI LETTER CANDRA E;14;2317;x0014;;
,e=;ऎ;U+090E ऎ DEVANAGARI LETTER SHORT E;15;2318;x0015;;
,e-;ए;U+090F ए DEVANAGARI LETTER E;16;2319;x0016;e;e 
,ai-;ऐ;U+0910 ऐ DEVANAGARI LETTER AI;17;2320;x0017;ai;ai 
,~o;ऑ;U+0911 ऑ DEVANAGARI LETTER CANDRA O;18;2321;x0018;;
,o=;ऒ;U+0912 ऒ DEVANAGARI LETTER SHORT O;19;2322;x0019;;
,o-;ओ;U+0913 ओ DEVANAGARI LETTER O;20;2323;x0020;o;o 
,au-;औ;U+0914 औ DEVANAGARI LETTER AU;21;2324;x0021;au;au 
,k;क;U+0915 क DEVANAGARI LETTER KA;22;2325;x0022;k;k
,kh;ख;U+0916 ख DEVANAGARI LETTER KHA;23;2326;x0023;kh;kh
,g;ग;U+0917 ग DEVANAGARI LETTER GA;24;2327;x0024;g;g
,gh;घ;U+0918 घ DEVANAGARI LETTER GHA;25;2328;x0025;gh;gh
,"n;ङ;U+0919 ङ DEVANAGARI LETTER NGA;26;2329;x0026;"n;ṅ
,c;च;U+091A च DEVANAGARI LETTER CA;27;2330;x0027;c;c
,ch;छ;U+091B छ DEVANAGARI LETTER CHA;28;2331;x0028;ch;ch
,j;ज;U+091C ज DEVANAGARI LETTER JA;29;2332;x0029;j;j
,jh;झ;U+091D झ DEVANAGARI LETTER JHA;30;2333;x0030;jh;jh
,~na;ञ;U+091E ञ DEVANAGARI LETTER NYA;31;2334;x0031;~n;ñ
,.t;ट;U+091F ट DEVANAGARI LETTER TTA;32;2335;x0032;.t;ṭ
,.th;ठ;U+0920 ठ DEVANAGARI LETTER TTHA;33;2336;x0033;.th;ṭh
,.d;ड;U+0921 ड DEVANAGARI LETTER DDA;34;2337;x0034;.d;ḍ
,.dh;ढ;U+0922 ढ DEVANAGARI LETTER DDHA;35;2338;x0035;.dh;ḍh
,.n;ण;U+0923 ण DEVANAGARI LETTER NNA;36;2339;x0036;.n;ṇ
,t;त;U+0924 त DEVANAGARI LETTER TA;37;2340;x0037;t;t
,th;थ;U+0925 थ DEVANAGARI LETTER THA;38;2341;x0038;th;th
,d;द;U+0926 द DEVANAGARI LETTER DA;39;2342;x0039;d;d
,dh;ध;U+0927 ध DEVANAGARI LETTER DHA;40;2343;x0040;dh;dh
,n;न;U+0928 न DEVANAGARI LETTER NA;41;2344;x0041;n;n
,.nna;ऩ;U+0929 ऩ DEVANAGARI LETTER NNNA;42;2345;x0042;;
,p;प;U+092A प DEVANAGARI LETTER PA;43;2346;x0043;p;p
,ph;फ;U+092B फ DEVANAGARI LETTER PHA;44;2347;x0044;ph;ph
,b;ब;U+092C ब DEVANAGARI LETTER BA;45;2348;x0045;b;b
,bh;भ;U+092D भ DEVANAGARI LETTER BHA;46;2349;x0046;bh;bh
,m;म;U+092E म DEVANAGARI LETTER MA;47;2350;x0047;m;m
,y;य;U+092F य DEVANAGARI LETTER YA;48;2351;x0048;y;y
,r;र;U+0930 र DEVANAGARI LETTER RA;49;2352;x0049;r;r
,rra;ऱ;U+0931 ऱ DEVANAGARI LETTER RRA;50;2353;x0050;;
,l;ल;U+0932 ल DEVANAGARI LETTER LA;51;2354;x0051;l;l
,.L;ळ;U+0933 ळ DEVANAGARI LETTER LLA;52;2355;x0052;;
,.LL;ऴ;U+0934 ऴ DEVANAGARI LETTER LLLA;53;2356;x0053;;
,v;व;U+0935 व DEVANAGARI LETTER VA;54;2357;x0054;v;v
,"s;श;U+0936 श DEVANAGARI LETTER SHA;55;2358;x0055;"s;ś
,.s;ष;U+0937 ष DEVANAGARI LETTER SSA;56;2359;x0056;.s;ṣ
,s;स;U+0938 स DEVANAGARI LETTER SA;57;2360;x0057;s;s
,h;ह;U+0939 ह DEVANAGARI LETTER HA;58;2361;x0058;h;h
,oe;ऺ;U+093A ऺ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN OE;59;2362;x0059;;
,ooe;ऻ;U+093B ऻ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN OOE;60;2363;x0060;;
,N;़;U+093C ़ DEVANAGARI SIGN NUKTA;61;2364;x0061;;
,.a;ऽ;U+093D ऽ DEVANAGARI SIGN AVAGRAHA;62;2365;x0062;;' 
,aa;ा;U+093E ा DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AA;63;2366;x0063;;ā 
,i;ि;U+093F ि DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN I;64;2367;x0064;;i 
,ii;ी;U+0940 ी DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN II;65;2368;x0065;;ī 
,u;ु;U+0941 ु DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN U;66;2369;x0066;;u 
,uu;ू;U+0942 ू DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN UU;67;2370;x0067;;ū 
,.r;ृ;U+0943 ृ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN VOCALIC R;68;2371;x0068;;
,.l;ॄ;U+0944 ॄ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN VOCALIC RR;69;2372;x0069;;
,~e;ॅ;U+0945 ॅ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN CANDRA E;70;2373;x0070;;
,e=;ॆ;U+0946 ॆ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN SHORT E;71;2374;x0071;;
,e;े;U+0947 े DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN E;72;2375;x0072;;
,ai;ै;U+0948 ै DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AI;73;2376;x0073;;
,~o;ॉ;U+0949 ॉ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN CANDRA O;74;2377;x0074;;
,o=;ॊ;U+094A ॊ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN SHORT O;75;2378;x0075;;
,o;ो;U+094B ो DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN O;76;2379;x0076;;
,au;ौ;U+094C ौ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AU;77;2380;x0077;;
,\&;्;U+094D ् DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA;78;2381;x0078;;///
%  
%  
,.o;ॐ;U+0950 ॐ DEVANAGARI OM;81;2384;x0081;;
%  
%  
%  
%  
%  
%  
%  
,q;क़;U+0958 क़ DEVANAGARI LETTER QA;89;2392;x0089;;
,.kh;ख़;U+0959 ख़ DEVANAGARI LETTER KHHA;90;2393;x0090;;
,.g;ग़;U+095A ग़ DEVANAGARI LETTER GHHA;91;2394;x0091;;
,z;ज़;U+095B ज़ DEVANAGARI LETTER ZA;92;2395;x0092;;
,R;ड़;U+095C ड़ DEVANAGARI LETTER DDDHA;93;2396;x0093;;
,Rh;ढ़;U+095D ढ़ DEVANAGARI LETTER RHA;94;2397;x0094;;
,f;फ़;U+095E फ़ DEVANAGARI LETTER FA;95;2398;x0095;;
,yy;य़;U+095F य़ DEVANAGARI LETTER YYA;96;2399;x0096;;
,.rr-;ॠ;U+0960 ॠ DEVANAGARI LETTER VOCALIC RR;97;2400;x0097;.rr;ṝ 
,.ll-;ॡ;U+0961 ॡ DEVANAGARI LETTER VOCALIC LL;98;2401;x0098;.ll;ḹ 
,.ll;ॢ;U+0962 ॢ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN VOCALIC L;99;2402;x0099;;
,.rr;ॣ;U+0963 ॣ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN VOCALIC LL;100;2403;x0100;;
,|;।;U+0964 । DEVANAGARI DANDA;101;2404;x0101;;
,||;॥;U+0965 ॥ DEVANAGARI DOUBLE DANDA;102;2405;x0102;;
,0;०;U+0966 ० DEVANAGARI DIGIT ZERO;103;2406;x0103;;
,1;१;U+0967 १ DEVANAGARI DIGIT ONE;104;2407;x0104;;
,2;२;U+0968 २ DEVANAGARI DIGIT TWO;105;2408;x0105;;
,3;३;U+0969 ३ DEVANAGARI DIGIT THREE;106;2409;x0106;;
,4;४;U+096A ४ DEVANAGARI DIGIT FOUR;107;2410;x0107;;
,5;५;U+096B ५ DEVANAGARI DIGIT FIVE;108;2411;x0108;;
,6;६;U+096C ६ DEVANAGARI DIGIT SIX;109;2412;x0109;;
,7;७;U+096D ७ DEVANAGARI DIGIT SEVEN;110;2413;x0110;;
,8;८;U+096E ८ DEVANAGARI DIGIT EIGHT;111;2414;x0111;;
,9;९;U+096F ९ DEVANAGARI DIGIT NINE;112;2415;x0112;;
%  
,…;ॱ;U+0971 ॱ DEVANAGARI SIGN HIGH SPACING DOT;114;2417;x0114;;
,~a-;ॲ;U+0972 ॲ DEVANAGARI LETTER CANDRA A;115;2418;x0115;;
,oe-;ॳ;U+0973 ॳ DEVANAGARI LETTER OE;116;2419;x0116;;
,ooe-;ॴ;U+0974 ॴ DEVANAGARI LETTER OOE;117;2420;x0117;;
,aw-;ॵ;U+0975 ॵ DEVANAGARI LETTER AW;118;2421;x0118;;
,ue-;ॶ;U+0976 ॶ DEVANAGARI LETTER UE;119;2422;x0119;;
,uue-;ॷ;U+0977 ॷ DEVANAGARI LETTER UUE;120;2423;x0120;;
,mdd;ॸ;U+0978 ॸ DEVANAGARI LETTER MARWARI DDA;121;2424;x0121;;
,zh;ॹ;U+0979 ॹ DEVANAGARI LETTER ZHA;122;2425;x0122;;
,Y;ॺ;U+097A ॺ DEVANAGARI LETTER HEAVY YA;123;2426;x0123;;
,gg;ॻ;U+097B ॻ DEVANAGARI LETTER GGA;124;2427;x0124;;
,jj;ॼ;U+097C ॼ DEVANAGARI LETTER JJA;125;2428;x0125;;
,?;ॽ;U+097D ॽ DEVANAGARI LETTER GLOTTAL STOP;126;2429;x0126;;
,.DD;ॾ;U+097E ॾ DEVANAGARI LETTER DDDA;127;2430;x0127;;
,bb;ॿ;U+097F ॿ DEVANAGARI LETTER BBA;128;2431;x0128;;
,c0;꣠;U+A8E0 ꣠ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT ZERO;129;43232;x0129;;
,c1;꣡;U+A8E1 ꣡ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT ONE;130;43233;x0130;;
,c2;꣢;U+A8E2 ꣢ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT TWO;131;43234;x0131;;
,c3;꣣;U+A8E3 ꣣ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT THREE;132;43235;x0132;;
,c4;꣤;U+A8E4 ꣤ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT FOUR;133;43236;x0133;;
,c5;꣥;U+A8E5 ꣥ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT FIVE;134;43237;x0134;;
,c6;꣦;U+A8E6 ꣦ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT SIX;135;43238;x0135;;
,c7;꣧;U+A8E7 ꣧ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT SEVEN;136;43239;x0136;;
,c8;꣨;U+A8E8 ꣨ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT EIGHT;137;43240;x0137;;
,c9;꣩;U+A8E9 ꣩ COMBINING DEVANAGARI DIGIT NINE;138;43241;x0138;;
%  
,filler;꣹;U+A8F9 ꣹ DEVANAGARI GAP FILLER;154;43257;x0154;;
,caret;꣺;U+A8FA ꣺ DEVANAGARI CARET;155;43258;x0155;;
,head;ꣻ;U+A8FB ꣻ DEVANAGARI HEADSTROKE;156;43259;x0156;;
,siddham;꣼;U+A8FC ꣼ DEVANAGARI SIGN SIDDHAM;157;43260;x0157;;
,jom;ꣽ;U+A8FD ꣽ DEVANAGARI JAIN OM;158;43261;x0158;;
,ayno;ꣾ;U+A8FE ꣾ DEVANAGARI LETTER AY;159;43262;x0159;;
,ayno;ꣿ;U+A8FF ꣿ DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AY;160;43263;x0160;;
,\#;…;;161;0;x0161;;
%,..;.;;162;0;x0162;;
}
\mfssortaseq[x]{devatranslit}{<}{1}


xascii2deva mapping:

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\mfslistaseq[x]{devatranslit}[
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n},
formatb=\fdevb\Large,
]
\end{multicols}

\translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n},
formatb=\fdevb,
]
{data a-biicii.  kuul bananas s\&kuul }

.dh is set up as 
\translit[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n},
fieldb=3,
formatb=\fdevb,%\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small,
placeholder=4,
]{.dh}
and maps to
\translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n},
fieldb=2,
formatb=\fdevb,
placeholder,
]{.dh}.


\newpage
xascii2unicode

\mfslistaseq[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n},
fieldb=3,
%formatb=\fdevb\small,
]


\newpage
By record number

\mfssortaseqnum[x]{devatranslit}{>}{4} %sort on record number

\mfslistaseq[x]{devatranslit}[
fieldb=2,
formatb=\fdevb\Large,
fielda=3,
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small,
]



\newpage
By Unicode codepoint

\mfssortaseqnum[x]{devatranslit}{>}{5} 

\mfslistaseq[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=3,
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small,
fieldb=2,
formatb=\fdevb\huge\color{blue},
]

\newpage
deva2velt

\mfssortaseq[x]{devatranslit}{<}{2} 

\begin{multicols}{4}
\mfslistaseq[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=2,
formata=\fdevb,
fieldb=7,
formatb=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small,
]
\end{multicols}

\newpage
velt2deva

\mfssortaseq[x]{devatranslit}{<}{7} 


\begin{multicols}{4}
\mfslistaseq[x]{devatranslit}[
fieldb=2,
formatb=\fdevb,
fielda=7,
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small,
]
\end{multicols}


\newpage
velt2iast

\mfssortaseq[x]{devatranslit}{<}{7} 


\begin{multicols}{4}
\mfslistaseq[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=7,
formata=\usefont{T1}{lmtt}{m}{n}\small,
fieldb=8,
formatb=\fipa,
fieldc=2,
formatc=\fdevb,
]
\end{multicols}


\newpage
78 

\mfssortaseq[x]{devatranslit}{<}{7} 

\translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=7,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=8,
formatb=\fipa,
showoriginal=true,
intermediate=2,
]{
raamo raajama.ni sadaa vijayate raama.m rame"sa.m bhaje |
}

\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{Velthuis to Deva}:

\translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=2,
formatb=\fdevb,
showoriginal=true,
]{raamo raajama.ni sadaa vijayate raama.m rame"sa.m bhaje |}

\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{Velthuis to IAST}:

\translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=7,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=8,
formatb=\fipa,
intermediate=2,
]{
raamo raajama.ni sadaa vijayate raama.m rame"sa.m bhaje |}

\bigskip
An example record, which looks like this as raw text, 
{\fdevb\color{blue} ,.dh;ढ;U+0922 ढ DEVANAGARI LETTER DDHA;35;2338;x0035;.dh;ḍh}, 
has these fields:

\bigskip
.dh (in xascii mapping, superset of Velthuis) [field 1]

= \translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=2,
formatb=\fdevb,
showoriginal=false,
placeholder,
]{.dh} [field 2] 

= \translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=3,
formatb=\fdevb,
]{.dh} [field 3]

= \translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=4,
formatb=\fipa,
]{.dh} (record number) [field 4]

= \translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=5,
formatb=\fipa,
]{.dh} (Unicode codepoint, decimal) [field 5]

= \translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=6,
formatb=\fipa,
]{.dh} (ID, experimental) [field 6]

= \translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=7,
formatb=\fipa,
]{.dh} (Velthuis) [field 7]

= \translitx[x]{devatranslit}[
fielda=1,
formata=\fipa,
fieldb=8,
formatb=\fipa,
]{.dh} (IAST) [field 8]



\end{document}
```

Code has been shoe-horned to fit into answer-box's 30k character limit.

Comment: Interesting note: for mapping the mappings, the most efficient method seems to be a two-step star-scheme (rather than one-step *n*-pairwise), where, to get A->B, A is converted to deva, and then the deva is converted to B, with the inherent `a` added or removed as appropriate.

Comment: Also: doing the regex on token lists (the argument of a transliteration command) means that the mapping has been moved out of the font-level and into the Latex-code level.