# Scanning use error while compiling Devanagari text

Tags: indic

I tried to run the Latex code posted by Stephen Kottwiz as an answer to this question: [How to make Sanskrit Title in Devanagari Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40862/how-to-make-sanskrit-title-in-devanagari-package)

Here's the same code repeated:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{fontspec,bera}
\begin{document}
\title{{\dn vivekachoodama.ni}}
\author{Sri Sankaracharya}
\maketitle
\begin{flushleft}
{\dn sarvavedaantasiddhaantagocara.m tamagocara.m | \\ govinda.m paramaananda.m {sad}guru.m pra.nato.asmyaham ||  1}


\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

I tried using PDFLatex to process the code and am getting the following error.
`line 0: File ended while scanning use of \iow_wrap_loop:w`

Can anyone shed any light on this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `fontspec` is being loaded, you need to process the example with xelatex; however, the original code won't work as expected (using xelatex) and will produce the error message

```
) Runaway argument? \q_stop \exp_args:NNo \group_end: \iow_term:n \l__iow_wrap_tl \iow_term:n \ETC. ! File ended while scanning use of \__iow_wrap_loop:w. <inserted text> 
                \par  l.269 \luatex_if_engine:T
                          { \RequirePackage{fontspec-luatex} \endinput } ?
```

in order for the example to work (at least in TeX Live2012) it's necessary to load `fontspec` *before* `devanagari` (and the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages should not be loaded):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{bera}

\title{{\dn vivekachoodama.ni}}
\author{Sri Sankaracharya}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{flushleft}
{\dn sarvavedaantasiddhaantagocara.m tamagocara.m | \\ govinda.m paramaananda.m {sad}guru.m pra.nato.asmyaham ||  1}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

and a warning about some fonts not being available:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/fve/m/n' undefined (Font)
      using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

Not loading the `bera` package suppresses the warning.

If you want to process with pdflatex, remove the `fontspec` package (and you can again load `fontenc` and `inputenc`):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\usepackage{bera}

\title{{\dn vivekachoodama.ni}}
\author{Sri Sankaracharya}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{flushleft}
{\dn sarvavedaantasiddhaantagocara.m tamagocara.m | \\ govinda.m paramaananda.m {sad}guru.m pra.nato.asmyaham ||  1}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

This time no warning is produced.